# Keras networks comparison

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I am passing course at datacamp on keras modeling. Following this, I have question regarding the model optimization. On picture you may see models's loss values plots

- Red line: 2 hidden layers with 10 nodes
- Blue line: 2 hidden layers with 100 nodes

According to the course blue line, with 100 nodes, performs better than red one. However, it fluctuates and gives rise to doubts in me.

**Question**: Is blue model performs better than red one?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE Datascience. I agree with you that the blue curve is a bit unstable, but as we always keep only the best result when training a network, we can say that blue went way below the best red curve did, so it should give better results.